# Trigger jenkins hudson.model.Job programmatically from jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jobs

I am struggling to figure out some sample example to trigger hudson.model.Job from plugin:

```
private void triggerPipelineJobs(){

    for (Job<?,?> job : Jenkins.getInstance().getAllItems(Job.class)) {
        System.out.println("job is : " + job.getName());
        //how to trigger this jenkins pipeline job
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run all Jenkins jobs (including pipelines), I use the following:

```
import hudson.model.*;

// get all jobs   
jobs = Hudson.instance.getAllItems(Job.class);

// iterate through the jobs
for (j in jobs) {
  // first check, if job is buildable
  if (j instanceof BuildableItem) {
     // run that job
     j.scheduleBuild();
  }
}
```

I think the part you are looking for is the `scheduleBuild()` method which you could call on your `job` variable in your for loop.